# Use of pointers with file-reading program

Tags: c, file, pointers

I'm working on a school assignment, and it's working fine, but I have a feeling I'm over-using pointers, and I just can't think of a way to not pass a triple pointer to the function `readFile`.

I'd be more than grateful for your suggestions, and if you have any other suggestions on how to improve my code I'd be glad to hear those too!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define handle_error(message) \
    do { perror(message); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while(0)
int readFile(char ***names, FILE *file, int *size);
void *_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

int main(void) {
    char **names;
    int names_size;
    FILE *file;
    int chars_read;
    int i;

    names = NULL;
    file = NULL;
    names_size = 0;
    chars_read = 0;

    file = fopen("names", "r");
    readFile(&names, file, &names_size);
    printf("%s\n", names[0]);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int readFile(char ***names_p, FILE *file, int *size) {
    int chars_read;
    int line;
    int chunk_size;
    int name_size;
    int name_length;
    char cur_char;
    char **names;
    char *name;

    name = NULL;
    names = NULL;
    line = 0;
    name_length = 0;
    name_size = 0;
    chunk_size = 2;
    chars_read = 0;
    while((cur_char = fgetc(file)) != EOF && cur_char != '\r'){
        if(cur_char == '\n') {
            if(name_size > 0) {
                names = _realloc(names, sizeof(char*) * (line+1));
                names[line] = _realloc(name, name_length + 1);
                names[line][name_length] = '\0';
                name_size = 0;
                name_length = 0;
                name = NULL;
                line++;
        } 
    } else {
            if(name_size < name_length + 1) {
                name = _realloc(name, 
                    sizeof(char) * (name_size = 
                    (name_size + 1) * chunk_size));
            }
            name[name_length] = cur_char;
            name_length++;
        }
        chars_read++;
    }
    *names_p = names; 
    *size = line;
    return chars_read;
}

void *_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    void *temp = realloc(ptr, size);
    if(temp == NULL) {
        int error = errno;
        if(error == ENOMEM) printf("size: %d\n", error);
        handle_error("realloc");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your tripple pointer is indeed unnecessary - just return the `char**` from `readFile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Introduction

You'll see that I made a lot of comments below, but if you're just starting to learn C, then your code is not at all bad. C is a tough language to write robust code in: it provides many many ways to go wrong, and even the most expert and experienced programmers don't always succeed in avoiding the traps and pitfalls.

I like your attention to error handling, that you check the result of `realloc`, that you remember to close your file handle, and that you use the symbols `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` to make it clear what you mean.

#### 2. Bugs

1. You don't check whether there were in fact any names in the file before printing the first of them. If the file was empty then this would result in undefined behaviour:

   ```
   $ clang cr27281.c
   $ cat /dev/null > names
   $ ./a.out
   Segmentation fault: 11
   ```
2. You don't check the result of `fopen`. If this call failed then you'd end up trying to read from the file handle `NULL`:

   ```
   $ rm names
   $ ./a.out
   Segmentation fault: 11
   ```

#### 3. Other comments on your code

1. If you need to return multiple values from a function, then why not use a structure? You could declare a structure like this:

   ```
   typedef struct name_array_s {
       char **names;         /* Array of names, allocated with malloc. */
       size_t count;         /* Count of names in the 'name' array. */
   } *name_array_t;
   ```

   and then `readFile` could take a `name_array_t` as its first argument.
2. There's no comment or documentation explaining the interface to `readFile`. What is this function supposed to do and how are you supposed to call it? Imagine coming back to this code in a couple of years' time when you have forgotten all about it. Do you really want to have to reverse-engineer it to figure out what it does?
3. The variable `names_size` is an `int`, but it counts the number of entries in the `names` array and it can never legitimately be negative. And there are common platforms where `INT_MAX` is 2147483647, but where you have enough memory to store many more objects than that. So why not make `names_size` a `size_t`?
4. Similarly for the result of the function `readFile`.
5. Consider using `abort()` in your error handler instead of `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. When running under the debugger, `abort()` drops you straight into the debugger prompt with a good chance of being able to find useful information in the backtrace, but `exit()` just quits the program, leaving you none the wiser.
6. It's a bit restrictive that the file has to be named `names`. Why not take the name on the command line in `argv[1]`?
7. This line:

   ```
   if(error == ENOMEM) printf("size: %d\n", error);
   ```

   has four problems! First, error messages should go to standard error, not (as here) standard output, so you need `fprintf(stderr, ...)`. Second, you want `size` instead of `error` in the call to `printf`. Third, `size` is a `size_t` but you are using a `%d` format specifier which takes an `int`, so this results in undefined behaviour. Fourth, by putting the `if` and the `printf` on the same line, you've made it impossible (in most debuggers) to set a breakpoint on the `printf`. I would write:

   ```
   if(error == ENOMEM)
       fprintf(stderr, "size: %lu\n", (unsigned long)size);
   ```
8. The C language allows you to combine the declaration of a variable and its initialization, so instead of writing the repetitive

   ```
   char **names;
   int names_size;
   FILE *file;
   int chars_read;
   int i;

   names = NULL;
   file = NULL;
   names_size = 0;
   chars_read = 0;
   ```

   you can write

   ```
   char **names = NULL;
   int names_size = 0;
   FILE *file = NULL;
   int chars_read = 0;
   int i;
   ```
9. After making the change above, it becomes obvious that the variable `i` is unused. But shouldn't your compiler have complained about that? When writing a new program it's well worth turning on as many error-detecting features as you can, for example if you're using GCC it's a good idea to use a comprehensive set of flags like `-ansi -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -Werror`.
10. The variable `chars_read` is also unused.
11. Having an assignment buried inside an expression seems error-prone and hard to understand (especially when broken across lines like this):

    ```
    name = _realloc(name, 
        sizeof(char) * (name_size = 
        (name_size + 1) * chunk_size));
    ```

    I prefer to keep the code simple:

    ```
    name_size = (name_size + 1) * chunk_size;
    name = _realloc(name, sizeof(char) * name_size));
    ```
12. `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), so you don't need it here (it doesn't do any harm, though).

    > §6.5.3.4.3 When [`sizeof` is] applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.
13. `chunk_size` is poorly named: it's not a size, it's an exponent that controls the exponential growth of the `name` buffer.

#### 4. Performance

Your algorithm for allocation involves reallocating the `names` array each time a new line is reached in the file. This is wasteful, because each time this array is reallocated, the contents may have to be copied across to the new region of memory, potentially making it O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

If your files are short then you may prefer not to worry about this, but after I did a simple rewrite of your `readFile` function to do less reallocation, I was able to get a speedup of more than 3× in test cases with many lines, like this one:

```
$ yes '' | head -10000000 | nl -ba > names
$ time ./names-old > /dev/null
real    0m4.136s
user    0m3.777s
sys     0m0.333s
$ time ./names-new > /dev/null
real    0m1.248s
user    0m0.946s
sys     0m0.287s
```